# Identify Modified Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, last-modified-date

I created a share point list  and it will modified by 4 users, all of them should modified each input by confirming at their levels, I can not monitor their engagement because Share Point shows last modified user. Is there an option to figure out all modified users & time which they hv taken.?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution you can implement is to have a multi-line text field that can keep a rolling log of who modifies an item.  Then use a workflow on modified to write the `Modified` and `ModifiedBy` time to the field.  That way you can keep a rolling log in a field attached to that item.  For Instance you would set the field in a workflow to

```
<FieldName>
[Modified] - [ModifiedBy]
```

preserving the previous entries in the list and adding the new ones.

Comment: BigRaj , Thank You ,, can you explain more about it,, I am new one to share point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audit log reports.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527

but it can not be confirmed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Audit is good feature for this requirement.

[image]

While if you just want to monitor it for few users, you may configure Alert for this list/listitem.

https://danielglenn.com/enable-alerts-for-sharepoint/